# Word Splitting on options substitution

Tags: bash, shell, curl

In the following shell script I am unable to set a user-agent with spaces in it. I am getting word splitting. The bit after the first space (i.e. "(Macintosh;") is being interpreted by curl as a url.

If I type it in into the console it work fine but not when I use substitution.

```
PARAMS="-v"
PARAMS="${PARAMS} --user-agent \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko)\"" #does not work
#PARAMS="${PARAMS} --user-agent \"Mozilla/5.0\"" #works

curl ${PARAMS} $1 > results.txt
```

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: try using single quotes inside the dbl-quotes to 'group' the user-agent. i.e. `PARAMS="${PARAMS}....'mozz....' ..."` Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is explained in the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

The solution is a slightly different syntax.

```
PARAMS=(-v)
PARAMS+=( "-A Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko)")
curl "${PARAMS[@]}" $1 > results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

From here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

> These quote characters (", double quote and ', single quote) are a syntax element that influences parsing. It is not related to eventual quote characters that are passed as text to the commandline! The syntax-quotes are removed before the command is called!

So there is a fundamental difference between `cmd "my args"` and `myargs="\"my args\""; cmd $myargs`.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the spaces with %20

You can do this in the script if you want like:

```
str_replace ( ' ', '%20', 'what you need here' );
```

Hope this helps.